# How to catch a disconnected serial port in c#?

Tags: c#, user-interface, bluetooth, connection, invoke

So I have a C# windows form application with a GUI that allows me to connect to an Arduino via a Bluetooth Serial connection and I want to turn the GUI background RED when the connection is broken.

I have created an ErrorHandler in my connectToArduino function but it does not seem to be working properly. When I pull the power on the Arduino, the GUI does not turn red!

```
  private void connectToArduino()
      {
            string selectedPort = comboBox1.GetItemText(comboBox1.SelectedItem);
            portArduino = new SerialPort(selectedPort, 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
            portArduino.RtsEnable = true;
            portArduino.DtrEnable = true;

            try
            {
                portArduino.Open();
                isConnectedArduino = true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                label8.Text = "Connection to Micro Failed. Try Again";
            }

            portArduino.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
            portArduino.ErrorReceived += new SerialErrorReceivedEventHandler(ErrorReceivedHandler);

            button1.Text = "Disconnect";
            enableControlsArduino();
        }
```

Error Handler:

```
    private void ErrorReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialErrorReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            this.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }));
    }
```

Comment: If you debug your application, does the program flow ever enter that method?

Comment: @silkfire It does not, I tried adding code for a Console.WriteLine and a SoundPlayer but neither task was completed when I unplugged the Arduino. I tried putting these commands both with the Invoke and without it.

Comment: Are you constantly checking on the status of the port? It looks like the `connectToArduino()' method checks once but doesn't check again.

Comment: @silkfire It creates and opens the port but then never goes back to that function again. I thought that was the purpose of the SerialErrorReceivedEventHandler to constantly be checking for errors in the connection (i.e. disconnection). My SerialDataReceivedEventHandler constantly checks for incoming data and completes actions in that function. I want the SerialErrorReceivedEventHandler to do the same thing

Comment: You must handle WM_DEVICECHANGE message to get notification when BT device disconnected.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko how would I go about capturing that message?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.message?view=netframework-4.8